# Size relative to line thickness/invariant under scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to I realize a dot (here just drawn as a circle) which stays the same size 
no matter how I scale the image.

Here is the example.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Probably I should use node instead of drawing another circle.

I used to use a node with ${\bullet}$ but this is not precisely centered and I cannot control the size.

**edit**
The following works partially, but not for a not centered point:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill[shift only] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\fill[shift only] (1,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill[shift only] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\fill[shift only] (1,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill[shift only] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\fill(1,0) {[shift only] circle (1pt)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Alternatively**, how to draw a dot at a specific point having a fixed size w.r.t. to the line thickness, e.g. 1.5x as thick as a `thick` line.

Comment: which one is the wrong one and with negative scaling?

Comment: the points should stay at the end points of the line is scaled...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the nontranslational scaling via `shift only` key. This will keep the translational part of the transformation but will set the matrix to identity. If you also want to cancel the current transformation you can use `reset cm` key.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill[shift only] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For the edit

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,yscale=-0.3]
\draw[thick] (0.5,0.5)--(-0.2,-1);
\fill (0.5,0.5) circle[shift only,radius=1pt];
\fill (-0.2,-1) circle[shift only,radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Didn't know about this feature. Many thanks

Comment: Wow... You are great. This feature is nice indeed.

Comment: Still makes a problem because I also use xscale=-1 to reflect images.

Comment: @Marcel Change my example and it should be OK. Maybe your example is different in your actual case. I also feel like you are overusing scale keys.

Comment: The problem is the point is not always in (0,0) ...

Comment: @Marcel Does `\fill (2,1) {[shift only]circle(1pt)};` help?

Comment: @percusse I was thinking about something like this but still effects the center...

Comment: @Marcel Without your example, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I added it to the example

Answer (score 2):

The solution is easy, move the scale code inside the path. Don't apply it to the whole tikz code:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, scale=3] (0,0)--(1,0);
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This way around it would not help, but I can put the scale to the dot

Comment: @Marcel Yes, you may scale up the whole tikz box and then scale down the dot.

Comment: Yes the point is I want the size relative to the line width and the overall scale is arbitrary, because I have a lot pictures which are more complicated like this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to do some math when setting the dot's size:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\myscale}{1}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
  \draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
  \fill (0,0) circle (1pt/\myscale);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand{\myscale}{3}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
  \draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
  \fill (0,0) circle (1pt/\myscale);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This way you can control, which elements should be (relative) scaled and which not.

For easier reuse of already written code you can use it this way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\myimage}[2][1]{
 \begin{scope}[shift={#2}, scale=#1]
  \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \fill (0,0) circle (1pt/#1);
 \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \myimage{(0,1)};
  \myimage[3]{(0,0)};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The point is I have a lot of images with dots on lines. I want to rescale them but the dots should stay the same relative to the line width. I have no idea of the scale because it is nested and too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a bit messy solution. Still not considering it elegant. It is a combination of the other solutions so far...

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mydot}[1]{
 \begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
  \fill[shift only] (0,0) circle (1.3pt);
 \end{scope}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\mydot{(0,0)};
\mydot{(1,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\mydot{(0,0)};
\mydot{(1,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```