# How to use stroke width for positioning (without being affected by scale)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

## Question

I want to shift some TikZ coordinates in units of the line width (stroke width). When I use some externally defined length as the line width, it is not affected by scaling, which is what I want. However, coordinates, offset, or similar specified in that length are.

How can I specify some TikZ coordinate, offset, or similar in terms of the actually used line width? I prefer solutions that also work with non-integer multiples of the line width, but I am also interested in those that don’t.

## Example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\mylinewidth}
\setlength{\mylinewidth}{10pt}

\newcommand{\twolines}{
    \draw[line width=\mylinewidth, yshift= \mylinewidth] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[line width=\mylinewidth, yshift=-\mylinewidth] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \twolines
    \node[font=\tiny] {one line width};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \twolines
    \node[font=\tiny] {not one line width};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields:
[image: Output of example code]

I want the second pair of lines to have a distance of one line width like the first pair.

## What I found

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209370/28608) is similar. However, I cannot use `shift only` since in my case it is shifts that are affected. I could theoretically use a macro for the scale, but that would probably be very tedious in my actual application since I use many complex macros as in the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinates are scaled but line widths are not.

`pic`s are normally not scaled unless the `transform shape` option is provided.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\mylinewidth}
\setlength{\mylinewidth}{10pt}

\tikzset{
   twolines/.pic={
     \draw[line width=\mylinewidth, yshift= \mylinewidth] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
     \draw[line width=\mylinewidth, yshift=-\mylinewidth] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
      }
   }




\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic{twolines};
    \node[font=\tiny] {one line width};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \pic{twolines};
    \node[font=\tiny] {scaled but one line width};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \pic[transform shape]{twolines};
    \node[font=\tiny] {scaled but not one line width};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]